# In Windows 10, can I set a default "Open with" application for docker files?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows

Docker image files must be named `Dockerfile` with no extension.  I typically edit these files using Visual Studio Code. Whenever I want to open one, I need to right click it and select *Open With* and then select *Visual Studio Code* from the list.  For most files, which have a file extension, the *Open With* modal has a checkbox to remember the preferred application.  Is there anyway to set a preferred application for files based on anything other than file extension, so that I could just double-click a `Dockerfile` to edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use information from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/13653/how-to-set-the-default-program-for-opening-files-without-an-extension-in-windows) to assign files with no extension to a default program, but it seems it will apply to ALL files with no extension (docker or not).